# ArcMap - proportion of polygon in lon/lat grid cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, spatial-analyst

I have a polygon representing a river basin on a 1 X 1 degree lat/lon grid. I need to create a boundary using the grid cells as the boundary to best represent the outline of the basin. I would like to make a condition telling ArcMap to include the 1 X 1 cells for which the polygon accounts for more than 10% of the area of that cell. I've added an image to better explain what I am aiming to do with a rough outline in blue. Any help/advice would be great.

If the above is not possible, creating a matrix of % accounted for in the polygon would still be useful and I will manually draw[image: Example GIS]

EDIT: I realise the example I have drawn is 0.5 X 0.5 cells, but I need to do this for 1 X 1 grids. With the data I have the each grid starts at half degree so one cell e.g. 2.5 to 3.5N and 31.5 to 32.5E. Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: The most obvious solution I can think of would be (1) [convert your basin polygon to a raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon_to_Raster/001200000030000000/) with 1°x1° cells; (2) convert the basin raster back to a polygon. I am not sure whether the vector-to-raster conversion process would be able to handle your 10% criteria, however; the options are either "cell center" or "maximum area" (< 50%)...